# Other purposes of data streaming besides videos/audio

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming

I'm trying to understand the purposes of streaming (chiefly from a server to a visual client like a browser or an app). The basic concept of sending chunks of data instead of waiting for all the data to arrive is clear to me. I can easily think of use cases like loading audio or video, or maybe even photos. But are there any other use cases e.g. for sending textual data or jsons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've have used streaming to send all the records from a mysql table. So imagine there are millions of records and you want to extract all the records into an csv file. In this use case you cannot do a raw findAll without any filter/limit/offset, because it will try to take all the records into memory and when the table gets bigger it won't fit.

So instead of one findAll, i did several findAll's each returning about 50k records, for that i've used limit combined with offset. After each query i sent that chunk of 50k records into the stream and then query again for another 50k records. Did this in a recursive way until there are no more records (controlled this with the limit and offset).
I had an rest endpoint, so when a user hit the endpoint it downloads that .csv file with all the table records.

I've found a article about it with postgres: https://medium.com/geoblinktech/how-to-export-a-postgresql-table-as-csv-with-node-js-streams-578d53434e80 (this uses the `COPY` operator)